# Can we write plugin for JVM

Tags: java, plugins, jvm

Is it possible to write a plugin for JVM(Oracle)? If we can, then which language can we use. I think mostly it would be C++.

Comment: What would you want this plugin to do?

Comment: Of course you can. But what this plugin do you suppose to do?
Please do not put vague queries here. Be clear with your requirement and problem by putting some efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to customise the JVM itself? Or just call native code?

- If the former, you are probably better off starting with the OpenJDK, which is open source and you can customise it to your heart's content. It would be a lot of work though: are you sure you really need to do this?
- If the latter, then it is certainly possible and relatively easy: take a look at [Java Native Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access)

Comment: It seems things I would like to experiment requires me to go with the first option.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to "plugins" for the JVM would in my opinion be either an Annotation Processor or a Java Agent. An Annotation Processor kan "extend" the compiler  e.g to perform some custom verification steps, or to generate extra source code. An Agent is a runtime component that e.g kan intercept classloading and emit bytecode when loading classes, amongst other usage areas.